# XHTML2FO.xsl gives error for nested html table tag while converting to PDF

Tags: html, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

This is my HTML and i am using XHTML2FO.XSL to transform the same to PDF. But i am getting error : **(Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-row" is missing child elements. Required content model: (table-cell+) (No context info available)**

Please help.

HTML:
**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="nested"
                        width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Name:</td>
                                <td class="inputField">TEST-0000 0002</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Type:</td>
                                <td class="inputField">Change</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="nested"
                        width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Description:</td>
                                <td class="inputField"><pre>TEST-CR </pre></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Estimated Completion Date:</td>
                                <td class="inputField"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**

This is the XHTMl2FO.XSL:
**https://github.com/jeffrafter/xhtml2fo/blob/master/xhtml2fo.xsl**

Comment: The sample is tranformed to XSL-FO just fine using your linked stylesheet at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgf3. PDF output creation from the resulting XSL-FO also works fine there. Are you sure you are processing the shown input with the linked stylesheet and feed the *exact* result to FOP?

Comment: The original stylesheet is available from https://www.antennahouse.com/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets